# why does php-fpm crash all the time?

Tags: php

#### PHP

> PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2016 10:40:26) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

#### php-fpm

> PHP 7.0.2 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jan  7 2016 10:40:30) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.4.0RC3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

There are no error message in  php,nginx and php-fpm error log file, I only get a  php-fpm [crash report](https://gist.github.com/videni/7f2e70e67af4430333f78082eeb5ce73), 
anybody know why this happened?

Comment: What does your server setup look like? I assume nginx/php5-fpm/ubuntu? If so - could you show your site config, namely; `location ~ \.php$ {....}`

Comment: it's not an answer, just suggestion (which cannot resolve your problem, sry), maybe it's mac os x brew port issue.. is this problem appears on production server? .. you can use ( docker / vb ) + vagrant for dev-machine, it will be more identical to production server environment.

Comment: @Darren, it is my local development environment  , I have not delivered my project to  production server yet,  I will try that ,  as  Wizard says  it might be   mac os x brew port  issue.